# Couldn't find Journal in my Portal, what is it and the use for it?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using liferay 6.1 CE, I see that `Journal` is used for Search Purpose.

So I decided to also include it in my Portal.

But I couldn't find anything like `Journal` in my Portal? So what is `Journal` and what is it used for?

Please let me know if I am missing anything or my understanding is completely wrong?

Comment: Please tell us specifically what you want to include and where? I am not clear what you want to do

Comment: Question is not clear. You should be aware of the fact that journal is changed to Liferay Web Content in liferay version 5.x onwards.

Comment: What is Journal and what is the use of that ??

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. You say that you "see that Journal is used for Search Purpose", and then you say that you don't know what Journal is and what it's used for. This is a contradiction.

Then you say you decided to include it in your portal - while you don't know what it is. Why do you want to include it in your portal if you don't even know what it is?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [blog](http://www.liferay.com/web/bryan.cheung/blog/-/blogs/1940101) to know more about `Journal` in Liferay.

If you want to work with `JournalArticle` from Java API use  `com.liferay.portlet.journal.service.JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil`.

Answer (score 0):

From one of the comments on this [blog](http://www.liferay.com/web/bryan.cheung/blog/-/blogs/1940101) as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11746604/468763), the changes from Journal to Web-content from liferay 5.2 onwards:

```
Journal Content => Web Content Display
Journal Articles => Web Content List
Journal Content Search => Web Content Search
Journal => Web Content
```

So the search you are talking about is nothing but `Web-content Search` which in the API is still called as `Journal Content Search`.

Starting from Liferay 5.2, liferay has changed the display name for `Journal` to `Web-content` and have retained the database tables and the API names as before.